# Visual Studio 2015 Nuget package is not installing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am trying to install package  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis using Nuget

It does download a lot of packages and then it rolls back every thing and gives me the following error

An error occurred while downloading package 'System.Reflection.Metadata 1.2.0' from source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/'

Does someone have any solution for this  ?

Comment: What is the error?  Usually that message has another message after it.

Comment: Install-Package : An error occurred while downloading package 'System.Reflection.Metadata 1.2.0' from source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting -Version 1.2.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to temporary workaround it by installing beta version of this package:

```
Install-Package System.Reflection.Metadata -Pre
```

Comment: I marked your comment as the right answer  , you nailed it man . Thanks